# Version One - Fetching Dependencies using the rest api in the console

Tags: rest, api, console, versionone

Hello So I have been trying to fetch records using the Version one rest1-v1 api and I am currently testing the response using the API console provided by Version One. My query looks like 
rest-1.v1/Data/Story?sel=Name,Number,Scope.Name,Scope.ID,Dependencies&where=Number="StoryID"

Now to elaborate the story that I am trying to retrieve contains both upstream as well as downstream dependencies. Using the above query i can fetch the upstream dependencies and I have verified using the ID's returned with the V1 portal. Would there be a way to fetch the downstream dependencies as well by adding another specific selector in the query? Since the UI maps with the api assets using different endpoints is there one for downstream dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would there be a way to fetch the downstream dependencies as well by
>   adding another specific selector in  the query?

Yes.

Examining the metadata for Story , you can see attributes called

- Dependancies - Upstream Dependencies
- Dependants   - Downstream Dependencies

So you can use `rest-1.v1/Data/Story?sel=Name,Number,Scope.Name,Scope.ID,Dependencies,Dependants&where=Number="StoryID"`

> Since the UI maps with the api assets using different endpoints is
>   there one for downstream dependencies?

No.  Same endpoint. Different attribute.

Helpful tidbit:
You can do things like this 
`/rest-1.v1/Data/Story?sel=Dependencies,Dependants&where=Dependants;-Dependencies`

This will list Stories that have Upstream Deps and NO Downstream Deps.
  In general when you use the form `where=AttributeName` you are declaring that you want to return results under the condition that the **AttributeName** has some data in and its negation is indicated in this pattern `where=-AttributeName`.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question so that it may help someone who stumbles upon the issue I was facing. With some online reading up i figured out that the Version one API console's xsl url can provide all the attributes that are tied to a meta (Epics/Story/Tasks) so by visiting the link:

https://YOUR_SERVER_NAME/meta.v1/Story?xsl=api.xsl

Replace the Story with Epic or Task if one wishes to find the attributes for them.
One can see all the attributes relative to the Story and on close inspection I found out that since the upstream dependencies in the V1 UI were mapped with dependencies in the api similarly downstream dependencies in the V1 UI were mapped as dependants in the api. 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

https://your.server.name/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Story?where=Dependencies.Number='S-12345'

...where `S-12345` is the number of at least one of the upstream dependencies for any of the returned stories.

(Note that older versions of VersionOne used `B-` instead of `S-` by default for story numbers.)